# Sum multiple columns to a two column output/dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am exploring a rugby dataset where I am stuck on a bit of an issue. The dataset contains  matches played in the the Six Nations over a year, and the tries are put into two separate columns, which is  "Home try's" and "Away try's". I am trying to print out the output of the teams with the largest amount of try`s. Below is an example of how the dataset looks.

| Home | Away | Home try's | Away try's |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| England | France | 3 | 2 |
| Ireland | Scotland | 1 | 4 |
| France | Ireland | 1 | 0 |
| Scotland | England | 1 | 3 |

I have tried to put the home and away columns to a single column as a list and use the arguments df.explode and df.groupby argument to create a dataframe, but it doesnt work. Any tips on how I could solve this?

The ideal output would be:

| England | Scotland | France | Ireland |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 5 | 3 | 1 |

Answer (score 2):

How about this?

```
series_home = df.groupby('Home').sum()["Home try's"]
series_away = df.groupby('Away').sum()["Away try's"]
combined_series = series_home + series_away
combined_df = pd.DataFrame(combined_series).transpose()
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this in a way combining the two DFs and using a pivot.

```
df_Home = df[['Home', 'Home_Try']]
df_Away = df[['Away', 'Away_Try']]
df_Away.columns = [['Team', 'Tries']]
df_Home.columns = [['Team', 'Tries']]
df2 = pd.concat([df_Home, df_Away])
df2.columns = ['Team', 'Tries']
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df2, values='Tries', columns=['Team'], aggfunc=np.sum)
df_pivot
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the "Home" column as an index and sort the dataframe.
Create another frame by copying the "Away try's" column into it and setting the "Away" column as the index. I copy the "Home try's" column to the new frame. I count the amounts.

```
df = df.set_index("Home").sort_index()
df1  = pd.DataFrame(df["Away try's"].values, index=df["Away"]).sort_index()
df1["Home try's"] = df["Home try's"]

print(df1.sum(axis=1))
```

Output

```
Away
England     6
France      3
Ireland     1
Scotland    5
dtype: int64
```